# Can I clean up this jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
$('#EID').empty();
$('#EID').html(data);
```

Is it possible to simplify this with jQuery and do I really need the empty of the first line?

Comment: @Felix - I'm not disputing this but why no? Is Clive's answer inaccurate?

Comment: @ElRonnoco: I think that's 'no' to 'do I really need the empty of the first line?' (the second part of the question)

Comment: @Clive Thanks, I thought I'd parsed the comment correctly but hadn't :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `empty` no. Just the last line will do the trick.

```
 $('#EID').html(data);
```

If both lines are required for any reason, you could still simplify the code like this:

```
$('#EID')
  .empty()
  .html(data);
```

Answer (score 6):

Calling `html()` will replace the existing content so you just need to do this:

```
$('#EID').html(data);
```

As Connell notes in his answer, in another scenario if `html()` did *not* clear the HTML you could use function chaining to shorten your code: `$('#EID').empty().html(data);`. A lot of jQuery functions return the elements(s) upon which the function was first called to allow for this type of shorthand.